# How can I avoid duplicate rows in redshift unload command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table that has a total of  60 rows out of which  14 are unique , need to download the redshift data to s3 using unload command , will the unload command take care of the duplicates or will I have to mention something explicitly

Answer (score 0):

The [UNLOAD command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) takes a *select statement*. Therefore, you simply need to write the statement such that it only selects the rows you want.

For example:

```
unload ('select DISTINCT * from table')
to 's3://mybucket/unload/' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
```

Answer (score 0):

My select statement doesn’t have distinct still the s3 file created has unique value  only